# How can I find the optimal buy and sell points for a stock if I have a transaction cost?

Tags: python, algorithm

If I have a list of prices, say `[4,2,5,6,9,3,1,2,5]` and I have a transaction cost of $2 and I am able to buy and short sell then the optimal strategy is buy at 2 switch positions at 9 and and switch again at 1. So the optimal buy indices are `[1,6]` and the optimal sell indices are `[4]`. How can this be solved programmatically? Specifically I'm looking to be pointed in the right direction (i.e. This is a perfect case for A* ... or whatever) rather than a solution.

Comment: Could you explain the problem a little better? Do you jsut want to get the indicies of all elements of the list above / below particular values?

Comment: Or do you want to find the optimal strategy for buying an selling given a set of historic prices?

Comment: @will I'm trying to find the optimal strategy given a set of historic prices.

Comment: Is the optimal strategy not just to buy at the beginning of any run which climbs more than the transaction cost, and sell just before any price drop?

Comment: @will no, I don't think so. That won't give you optimal performance if there are small spikes that are less than the transaction cost.

Comment: Yah sorry, I missed that part out. I talk about it in the comments below. You just need to remove the combinations of sell/buy at adjacent indices if the difference is less than the transaction cost.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that optimal selling indices are those `i` such that
`price[i-1] < price[i]` and `price[i+1] <= price[i]` and for some `j > i`, `price[i] - price[j] > 2`. I don't know about names for an algorithm like that, but list comprehensions and the function `any` should be enough.

Comment: I think in the specific problem he's looking at, buying and selling is only considered at the end of runs. specifically runs larger than the transaction fee.

Comment: This still doesn't address the issue about what j to buy on. The transaction fee makes it complicated. If the price goes up and down by 1 for a while and then eventually goes down by 2, then because of the transaction fee it may be best to wait until the price eventually goes down by 2 to buy. And so forth, when it goes down by 2 it might be best to wait for even later j when the price goes down even more due to the transaction fee. This smells like a dynamic programming problem to me, or maybe some involved greedy method could solve it.

Comment: Exactly. It doesn't make it very complicated though, you just need to split the list into rises and falls, and then look at the size of each. Disregard anything less than two, and the remaining start and end indices are the optimal buy/sell points.

Comment: @will I disagree somewhat. Just because the difference exceeds 2 doesn't mean you should do the transaction at that point, because you may not be able to do any transaction after that until a later point when you could have made a better transaction. Or is that what you meant?

Comment: No, i'm saying you split the list into runs, and then any run with a difference of greater than the transaction cost gives you a beneficial sale. If i have `[1,2,3,4,5,4,5,6,7,8,9]` then i have two runs, but the end/beginning gap is less than two, so the buy/sell are ignored, and it would still give buy at `1` sell at `9`. I don't think i explained it well before.

Comment: I agree. My answer is wrong. Splitting by runs and ignoring those with endpoints differing in <= 4 seems to do the trick (4 because you must sell and buy for the interval to be considered, and then you lose 4).

Comment: Aah yes, didn't think to double the transaction fee. It's still a much easier answer than one requiring path of doing or any other complex algo.